# Select2 on datatable child parent

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2

I just want to ask if how to enable

```
$('.select').select2({tags:true})
```

in datatable when select element is hiding?

this is my sample code
https://jsfiddle.net/4vwLqr8n/

Comment: What exactly is not working? The [`tags`](https://select2.org/tagging) option appears to be working correctly in your Fiddle. What do you mean by "_when select element is hiding_"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @andrewJames - When datatable has + icon tags is not working

Comment: i just figure it out, i used this 
 drawCallback: function(settings){
  var api = this.api();           
                                    // Initialize custom control
  initDataTableCtrl(api.table().container());
 },

to call again select2 tags.